# Jquery get index of element type in parent

Tags: jquery, indexing, find

i tried searching but had no luck, i have an element with various elements inside i need to get the index of an element type selecting it by class

Example

```
<div>
    <span></span>
    <p></p>
    <span></span>
    <p></p>
    <span class="selected"></span>
    //i need to find this and know it's the third span
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `$('span').index($('.selected'));`

Comment: `-1` is the return value of `index()` when the target element cannot be found within the collection. Are you sure you included the wrapping `$()` on `$('.selected')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function for this.

`index()` can either be called on a collection and passed the target element, like so:

```
$('div span').index($('.selected'));
```

or called on the target element and passed a selector in which to search:

```
$('.selected').index('div span');
```

With your example HTML both of these will return `2`, which is the index of the `.selected` `<span>` within the `<div>`, only counting `<span>` elements. (Remember indexing starts from 0).

http://jsfiddle.net/uk35bny0/1/